# Vaex unable to open hdf5 created by pandas

Tags: python, hdf5, vaex

I am getting this error:

```
OSError: Could not open file: test/pd.hdf5, did you install vaex-hdf5? Is the format supported?
```

Yes I have installed vaex-hdf5

Here is a screenshot of the hdf5 I am attempting to open in vaex, opened in pandas:
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is actually explained in the [vaex documentation](https://vaex.io/docs/faq.html#Why-can%27t-I-add-a-new-column-after-filtering-a-vaex-DataFrame?): basically, pandas exports the data into row based format and vaex expects a column based format.